# Find Fourier Series of $f(x)=e^x+e^{-x}$

Tags: proof-verification, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Problem:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that:

1. $f(x)=e^x+e^{-x},\ \ \forall\ \ x \in [-\pi, \pi)$ and
2. $f(x+2\pi)=f(x),\ \ \forall\ \ x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Calculate the Fourier series of $f$.

**What I've done:**

First, I attempt to calculate the Fourier Coefficients.

1. Trying to find $a_0$:

$$
\begin{align}
a_0
& =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)dx}
=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{f(x)dx}
=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{(e^x+e^{-x})dx}
=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[e^x-e^{-x}\right]_{0}^{\pi}\\
& =\frac{1}{\pi}(e^{\pi}-1-e^{-\pi}+1)
=\frac{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}{\pi}
=\frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}
\end{align}
$$

2. Trying to find $a_n$:

$$
\begin{align}
a_n
& =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\cos(nx)dx}
=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{f(x)\cos(nx)dx}
=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{(e^x+e^{-x})\cos(nx)dx}\\
& =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^x\cos(nx)dx}
  +\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^{-x}\cos(nx)dx}
=I+J
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
I
& =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^x\cos(nx)dx}
=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[e^x\cos(nx)\right]_{0}^{\pi}
+\frac{2n}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^x\sin(nx)dx}\\
& =\frac{2}{\pi}(e^{\pi}\cos(n\pi)-1)
  +\frac{2n}{\pi}\left[e^x\sin(nx)\right]_{0}^{\pi}
  -\frac{2n^2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^x\cos(nx)dx}\\
& =\frac{2}{\pi}(e^{\pi}(-1)^n-1)
  +\frac{2n}{\pi}e^{\pi}\sin(n\pi)
  -n^2I
=\frac{2(e^{\pi}(-1)^n-1)}{(1+n^2)\pi}
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
J
& =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^{-x}\cos(nx)dx}
=\ ...\ 
=\frac{2(1-e^{-\pi}(-1)^n)}{(1+n^2)\pi}
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
a_n
& =I+J
=\frac{2(e^{\pi}(-1)^n-1)}{(1+n^2)\pi}
+\frac{2(1-e^{-\pi}(-1)^n)}{(1+n^2)\pi}
=\frac{2(e^{\pi}(-1)^n-e^{-\pi}(-1)^n)}{(1+n^2)\pi}\\
& =\frac{2(-1)^n(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi})}{(1+n^2)\pi}
=\frac{4(-1)^n\sinh(\pi)}{(1+n^2)\pi}
\end{align}
$$

3. Since $f$ is an even function, $b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\sin(nx)dx}=0$.

After finding the Fourier Coefficients, I attempt to find the Fourie Series expression:

$$
\begin{align}
s(x)
& =a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))
=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)\\
& =\frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{4(-1)^n\sinh(\pi)}{(1+n^2)\pi}}\cos(nx)\\
& =\frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}+\frac{4\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+n^2)}}\cos(nx)
\end{align}
$$

**Question:**

Is the approach I'm following and the result I've found correct? Is there a better way to tackle the above problem?

**Edit:**

As mentioned in a comment of mine under @Btzzzz's answer, what troubles me is the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ohj5breeor) Desmos produces for my series, whose amplitude is stuck at $21.789$ while the graph of $f$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Use the complex Fourier series representation.

Comment: Fourier series is meant for periodic functions. right? why don't we use Fourier transform here?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan fourier transform and fourier series are 2 different things with different meaning, also I am pretty sure that there is no simple result to fourier transform of $f(x)

Comment: Fourier transform is the representation of function, when the period approaches infinity.right?

Comment: Fourier Transforms are used to turn a signal *(periodic or not)* expressed in the time domain into a spectrum expressed in the frequency domain. I don't see how it's related to this question @ManeeshNarayanan.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I just tried to calculate the Fourier transform of this function, there is no nice form to that, the best one can hope to get is getting the Fourier transform using discrete Fourier transform, or FFT(which gives the same result), those will give a sample set of the transform

Comment: @AngelPolitis this is only partially true, Fourier transform works only for periodic function, but it allowed the period to have limit to infinity. This is important because Fourier transform was originally extension to the series and only after that t he transform was used to what we use it today normally. The history of Fourier analysis is very interesting and I would recommend you to read about this when you have the time. Also the transform itself is 4-periodic(using the transform 4 times will result the original function for most functions)

Answer (score 1):

This seems right to me but I think that using the complex coefficient will be easier:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{inx};\quad a_n=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}\;dx$$Where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Let's calculate $a_n$ shall we:

---

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi (e^x+e^{-x})e^{-inx}\;dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi 2 e^{-i n x} \cosh(x)\;dx=\cdots= \dfrac{i e^{-(1 + i n) x} ((n - i) e^{2 x} + n + i)}{n^2 + 1}{\LARGE|}_{-\pi}^\pi\\=\dfrac{4 (\sinh(\pi) \cos(\pi n) + n \cosh(\pi) \sin(\pi n))}{n^2 + 1}$$

We can simplify it by remembering that $n\in\Bbb N$ so $\sin(\pi n)=0,\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$:$$\dfrac{4 (\sinh(\pi) \color{blue}{\cos(\pi n)} + \color{red}{n \cosh(\pi) \sin(\pi n)})}{n^2 + 1}=\dfrac{4 \sinh(\pi)(-1)^n}{n^2 + 1}$$

Now dividing by $2\pi$ to get: $$a_n=\frac2{\pi}\dfrac{ \sinh(\pi)(-1)^n}{n^2 + 1}$$

---

In the end we get the sum $$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\frac2\pi\dfrac{ \sinh(\pi)}{n^2 + 1}e^{inx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, these kind of calculations are often long and tedious so there is no general shortcut. Something i like to use to verify my solution is correct is by plotting the series using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and comparing it to the graph of $f$. (Noting that it won't be exact since this is just an approximation of the function)

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using Desmos. In fact, it is the graph it produces for my series that troubles me. The graph of $f$ goes up to $\infty$ while the one for my series is stuck to $21.789$ as shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ohj5breeor). Shouldn't the graphs be close to identical?

Comment: Your solution is definitley correct, as long as the shape is accurate then this is what matters. Often approximations mess up when the function goes off to infinity suddenly